# JQuery.Ajax() success json

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have a problem with the success of my jquery funcion.

This is the script in js

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "filtra.php",
    dataType: 'json', 
    data: "livello:"+ liv+"&materia:"+mat,
    success: function (data) {
        for ( var x = 0; x < data.length; x++ ) {
            content = data[x].ID;
    alert(content);
    }
    }
});
```

And this is the php page.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['livello']) && isset($_POST['materia']) && isset($_POST['keyword'])) {
        $liv=$_POST['livello'];
        $mat=$_POST['materia'];
        $keyw=$_POST['keyword'];
        $dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $rows=array();
        try{
            $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username,'');}
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Attenzione: '.$e->getMessage();}
        $str="SELECT * FROM quesito";
        if($liv!="Tutte"){$str.=" WHERE '$liv'=Livello ";}
        if($mat!="Tutte" && $liv!="Tutte"){$str.="AND '$mat'=Materia ";}
        else if($mat!="Tutte" && $liv=="Tutte") {$str.=" WHERE'$mat'=Materia ";}
        $sql = $pdo->prepare($str);
        $sql->execute(); 
        $res = $sql->fetchAll();    
        echo json_encode($res);
        }
?>
```

There aren't any return..
Thanks for replies.

Comment: Please make sure to protect your code from SQL injection attacks. This: `if($liv!="Tutte"){$str.=" WHERE '$liv'=Livello ";}` is very bad practice. Escape or untaint the inputs, or better, use bind variables instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the `echo`

```
echo json_encode($res);
```

Edit: and miss-spelled `encode`

Comment: Do some basic debugging and come back to us with more information. Add an error handler to your ajax request for starters.